# How to verify HMAC java

Tags: java, hmacsha1

I've got the following code to compute Hmacs with a password:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException 
{
  String password = "password123";
  SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes(), "HmacSHA1");

  Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
  mac.init(keySpec);

  byte[] result = mac.doFinal("This is a test string".getBytes());

  System.out.println(new Base64().encodeAsString(result));
}
```

But I can't figure out how to verify it with a password, I'm reading the Java documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Concepts) but i can't  seem to find a verify function or anything, the section on HMACs is quite short.

How do i verify the HMAC with the password?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by verify?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Check the original string against the (hash + password) to verify integrity

Comment: You simply do the hashing again and check wether the results match. If either of the strings has the slightest difference, the hash will not match. If they match, you know that both input strings and both passwords matched, because the hash matches.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Make it as an answer, baby.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusWMahlberg.

Answer (score 5):

Just adding this as answer as mentioned by  "Markus W Mahlberg" for better viewing purpose.
*You simply do the hashing again and check wether the results match. If either of the strings has the slightest difference, the hash will not match. If they match, you know that both input strings and both passwords matched, because the hash matches*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/MAC.svg/661px-MAC.svg.png

Comment: Thanks, sorry for late acceptance. It's exactly what solved the purpose.